# Using nested dict as a lookup table for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, iteration, dataframe

I have calibration factors that need to be applied after specific dates and for certain ranges of instrument readings ie. a higher reading will require a different calibration factor. I am way I am trying to apply a lookup table that is based on the time and also the raw instrument reading through the use of a nested python dictionary.

Here is an example of the dataframe I am working with:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2013-05-06', '2013-07-20', freq='D')
data = random.random(size=(76,2)) * 10
df = DataFrame(data, index=dates, columns=['instrument 1','instrument 2'])
```

and here is an example of the nested dictionary with calibration factors for instruments after specific dates and based on the intrument reading.

```
caldates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-05-06','2013-07-09'])

calibration = {caldates[0]:{'instrument 1':{'multiply':{1:0.05, 3:0.04, 7:0.03}, 'offset':{1:5, 3:7, 7:10}},
                            'instrument 2':{'multiply':{1:0.06, 3:0.04, 7:0.005}, 'offset':{1:8, 3:10, 7:15}},

               caldates[1]:{'instrument 1':{'multiply':{1:0.05, 3:0.04, 7:0.03}, 'offset':{1:5, 3:7, 7:10}},
                            'instrument 2':{'multiply':{1:0.06, 3:0.04, 7:0.005}, 'offset':{1:8, 3:10, 7:15}},
```

As I said before the calibration factors done on a specific date should be applied after the date and also, the multiplier and offset used should be found from the key that is closest to the instrument reading.

is there a way to iterate through my dataframe to apply these calibration factors with the nested dict as a form of a lookup table?